# Nodal lines of wave equation on rectangular membrane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'd appreciate if someone could please let me know how to draw nodal lines. I don't really know how to do it and couldn't find much information with Google. I could find some info on nodal curves though, but nodal lines are something different.

Specifically, for the wave equation $$u_{tt}=c^2 (u_{xx}+u_{yy})$$
for $0<x<L$, $0<y<H$, $u(x,y,0)=f(x,y)$, $u_t(x,y,0)=g(x,y)$, with homogenous boundary conditions.

The only thing I know is that a nodal line is where an eigenfunction is always zero. In this case, we have two eigenfunctions: $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{H}\right)$. I think that these eigenfunctions are always zero only for $n,m=0$, please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, I don't know what nodal functions should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your equation by Fourier method, you will find that the solution is given by
$$
u(t,x,y)=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty A_{i,j}\cos (\omega_{i,j}t)v_{i,j}(x,y),
$$
where $w_{i,j}=\sqrt{\lambda_{i,j}},$ and $\lambda_{i,j}$ are the eigenvalues corresponding to the eigenfunction $v_{i,j}$. If you solved this problem, you should know that
$$
\lambda_{i,j}=\pi c\left(\frac{i^2}{L^2}+\frac{j^2}{H^2}\right)
$$
and
$$
v_{i,j}(x,y)=\sin\frac{\pi i x}{L}\sin\frac{\pi j y}{H}.
$$

By definition, the nodal curves are the curves in $(x,y)$ plane such that $v_{i,j}(x,y)=0$. Hence in your case you have
$$
\sin\frac{\pi i x}{L}\sin\frac{\pi j y}{H}=0,
$$
which is true for $x=\frac{Lk}{i},\,k=0,\ldots,i$ and $y=\frac{Lm}{j},\,m=0,\ldots,j$, which corresponds to the straight lines.

It is possible to have a more complicated structure of the nodal lines if there are such integers $i,j,m,k$ that
$$
\frac{i^2}{L^2}+\frac{j^2}{H^2}=\frac{m^2}{L^2}+\frac{k^2}{H^2}.
$$

In this case the expression for $v_{i,j}$ changes for
$$
v_{i,j}(x,y)=\sin\frac{\pi i x}{L}\sin\frac{\pi j y}{H}+\sin\frac{\pi m x}{L}\sin\frac{\pi k y}{H}\,,
$$
and the nodal lines can have very strange geometry.